# Why is "required" not working in my Angular form?

Tags: html, angular, forms, bootstrap-5

I am pretty new to angular. Below is my template file for a Register page in angular. I have added all labels and inputs inside the form tag. I have a button named Register of type submit. Why on clicking register default behavior of required is not displaying? I use bootstrap for styling.

```
 <div class="register-page">
        <div class="card register-form-box shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Register</h4>
            </div>
            <form class="card-body">
                <div class="form-gorup">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="username">Username</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName" name="username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-gorup mt-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="email">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-gorup mt-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="inpname">Infrastructure Provider Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="inpname" type="text" [(ngModel)]="inpName" name="inpname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-gorup mt-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-gorup mt-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold" for="repassword">Retype Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="repassword" type="password" [(ngModel)]="rePassword" name="repassword" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4 row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary w-75" type="submit" (click)="onRegister()">Register</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a routerLink="/login">Already registered?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your form control is correctly being marked as invalid due to the `required` attribute, but you have nothing in your HTML/CSS that is being triggered in response to the invalid state.

Check [the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms) for how to implement validation on template driven forms.

An example for your use case could be:

`.html`

```
<div class="form-gorup">
  <label
    class="fw-bold"
    for="username">
    Username
  </label>

  <input
   class="form-control"
   id="username"
   type="text"
   #UserName="ngModel"
   [(ngModel)]="userName"
   name="username"
   required />

  <p
    *ngIf="UserName.errors?.['required']"
    class="your-form-error-style">
    Username is required
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you are just interested in the validity of the input field itself for CSS styling, you could watch the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudoclasses on the input. For example:

`.html`

```
  <input
   class="form-control"
   id="username"
   type="text"
   [(ngModel)]="userName"
   name="username"
   required />
```

`.css`

```
input.form-control:valid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Note however that these only reflect the valid state, not the specific validator that failed. As a result, I would always opt for the first approach exposing the underlying `NgControl` with `#TemplateVariable="ngModel"`

Comment: Thankyou.
<form>
        <input type="text form-control" required>
        <button type="submit">HII</button>
    </form>
i have seen this normal piece of html code will trigger the validation if the input is empty or not. Why do this behavior lost in my code. Is it due to angular.

Comment: It is almost certainly not due to Angular, the `required` attribute still works as a validator on the native `<input>` field with/without `FormsModule` imported. I maintain that your fields will be being marked as invalid correctly. However I have expanded my answer to include another route you may consider, the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudoclasses. These may (or may not!) be being used by your global styles to style the `<input>`, if that's what you are expecting, and would not need access to the underlying `NgControl` to do so